# RTRIM(something) +' '+RTRIM(something) leads to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, trim

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have two nvarchar fields that I want to concatenate using RTRIM function.  However, when I do, all I get are NULL values.

Below is the sample function I'm using:

```
RTRIM(gis.dbo.tbl.Name1) + ' ' + RTRIM(gis.dbo.tbl.Name2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not posting as answer for it has been a long time since I last worked with SQL, but I'm pretty sure you want to use the CONCAT function intead of the `+` operator.

Comment: There are other fields in the view where the RTRIM function and + operator are used and they show what I'm expecting.

Comment: You could have provided an executable repro (`SELECT RTRIM('x') ...`). You should have. It would have allowed you to find the problem yourself because one of the inputs is NULL.

Comment: @Spidey - Not available until 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that your fields have values? If either of them are null, your code won't work. You could try like this instead to catch the null values:

```
RTRIM(ISNULL(gis.dbo.tbl.Name1, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(gis.dbo.tbl.Name2, ''))
```

Comment: Name1 is almost always populated, Name2 is sparsely populated.  So, unless Name1 and Name2 are not always populated, this won't work?

Comment: I meant your code won't work if both aren't populated and that would be the reason you are getting null. The code in my answer should work regardless. I updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works. I'm just curious if mine doesn't work because of the RTRIM function or is it because of the + operator?...which would cause the NULLs.

Comment: @mpboyle - Most operations involving `NULL` result in a `NULL`. The setting `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` can change that for concatenation with `+` but is deprecated and shouldn't be used. 2012+ has `CONCAT` that treats `NULL` as empty string.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge everyone!